# How to determine if the user clicked OK or CANCEL when exiting Silverlight?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Based on http://mark.mymonster.nl/2009/02/28/integration-of-browsers-unloading-with-silverlight/ I know when the user closes a browser window containing Silverlight, by use of javascript. This basically creates a popup window, where the user can stay on the page(by clicking CANCEL), or exit the page (by clicking OK).

I am interested in how I can determine if the user wants to exit the page, or continue to stay on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine that the user wants to exit the page because the Application_Exit will run and/or you can hook the browser `onunload` event in the same way you have the `onbeforeunload`.

The only way to determine that user doesn't want to exit is to wait and see if the Application_Exit **isn't** entered or the browser's `onunload` event **isn't** fired.

Why would you want to know that "the user considered leaving but then thought better of it" anyway?  On cancel nothing should have changed, its a **non-event**.